# lein2 - lein version fails due to org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector

Tags: clojure, leiningen

well this is strange:

```
> lein version
Mar 31, 2014 3:11:38 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host
Mar 31, 2014 3:11:38 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
```

why would it need an internet connection just to version? also afaik my network is working fine.

Comment: ok -- i don't know why this worked, but i deleted all the files in ./m2/repository and now its working

Comment: Maybe you have plugins active in your user profile, or are calling lein from a directory with a project.clj that uses plugins? I think that would cause lein to load those plugins (downloading them if necessary) before applying the task.

Answer (score 0):

ok -- i don't know why this worked, but i deleted all the files in ./m2/repository and now its working